# Why is switch not working as programmed?

Tags: c, embedded

When I am executing this code, the LED is ON by default whereas it should only be ON when switch is pressed. And when I press the switch, it turns off. Can anyone please explain me, what I am doing wrong with my code.

```
#include <lpc17xx.h>

#define SwitchPinNumber 11
#define LedPinNumber 6

void main()
{
    uint32_t switchStatus;

    SystemInit();

    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 = 0x000000; // Configure the Pins for GPIO;

    /* Configure the LED pin as output and SwitchPin as input */
    LPC_GPIO2->FIODIR = ((1 << LedPinNumber) | (0 << SwitchPinNumber));

    while (1)
    {
        /* Turn On all the leds and wait for one second */
        switchStatus = (LPC_GPIO2->FIOPIN >> SwitchPinNumber) & 0x01; // Read switch status
        if (switchStatus == 1)
        {
            LPC_GPIO2->FIOPIN = (1 << LedPinNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            LPC_GPIO2->FIOPIN = (0 << LedPinNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply reverse the bits and values and logic? So `0` becomes `1` and `1` becomes `0`? Something simple like that?

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: some chips have a reverse logic. 1 is off where 0 is on.

Comment: Oh by the way, `0` will always be `0`, no matter how much you shift it. If you want to clear a specific bit, use e.g. `LPC_GPIO2->FIOPIN &= ~(1 << LedPinNumber)`

Comment: Whether a 1 extinguishes or lights an LED depends entirely on how it is connected electronically.  Simply reverse the states.  This is not a programming question, it is an electronics question.

Comment: @Some programmer dude when I employ switch in another program its not working at all. Below is the code snippet.
 while(1)
 {
  
    while(switchStatus==0) 
   {
  for(i=0; i<=8; i++)
  {
   uart_init(Baudrate[i]);
   read();
   
   if(flag0==1)
    break;
  }
  
  if (flag0==1)
   Glow_GreenLED();
  else
  {
   Glow_RedLED();
   break;
}
   }
}
while(1);
 }

Comment: @Clifford Unfortunately bugs can happen at the hardware level as well, which means the program has to work around such bugs. For example by reversing the logic.

Comment: hignly unlikely this is a chip bug, very common to wire an led so that you have to short it to turn it on, historically an mcu can sink more than it sources.  Historically a part doesnt make it to market if it cant drive a high high and a low low and requires reverse logic.  This is both an EE stackexchange question and asked and answered a zillion tomes.  Also the OP should have done some testing ahead of time, like lighting the led on in one test and off in another, without the switch involved (to see what we are talking about).  Likewise the switch could be wired to pull up or down.

Comment: Generally you will have an input be pulled high either internally or externally then the switch will be wired to ground.  the LED wiring is a toss up, half the designs you turn the port bit on to make the output go to VCC(IO) and drive the led which then goes through a resistor to ground.  The other half of the time the resistor and led are tied to VCC and you set the bit to 0 to set the pin to ground to turn on the led.  Reading the schematic or talking to the hardware engineer is a requirement for this type of work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : But it is unlikely to be a bug; just by design.  It is not at all uncommon to drive an LED through a high-side transistor switch transistor switch https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transistors/applications-i-switches

Answer (score 0):

If this is actually a mechanical switch, then you must always:

- de-bounce the signal somewhere, usually done in code but can also be done with external RC filter.
- ensure that the signal is pulled to the inactive state with a pull resistor, external or internal. It is not clear from the question if you need this signal to be active high or active low.

These are very basic things that can be solved in either hardware or software. Your question shows no trace of doing any of the above, so it is unlikely that your program will ever work as intended.

Comment: Btw you can easily check the hw just by looking at the IO register in the memory map from your debugger. Often debuggers allow you to write directly to such registers, which can also be used to check if the LEDs are working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is working, but the logic is inverted.  This could either be because:

1. The switch you're reading pulls the input signal down, rather than up.  This means that when the switch is pressed, the logic is 0, rather than the 1 you were expecting. Or
2. The indicator LED is energised by driving the microcontroller pin low, rather than high as you were expecting.

Ideally you would have already looked at the schematic for the circuit you are controlling so you can work out the effect of the logic states, before writing the code to do something with it.

I expect you could simply change the line `if (switchStatus == 1)` to `if (switchStatus == 0)` to acheive your desired result, but you should also do some investigation of your circuit to determine if either of the reasons I suggested is causing the unexpected result and avoid repeating this mistake in future.